# Leaflet shapes move on zoom

Tags: leaflet

When I zoom in after loading the page, this happens:

https://gyazo.com/76b0458b1cd836a3b3d6ddaa493585da (I zoomed in and out with the mouse wheel)

However, after I move the map with the mouse just a bit, the issue is gone and everything functions perfectly... until I reload the page.

Does anyone have an idea why could this be happening?

Here I managed to recreate the issue: https://plnkr.co/edit/RD9yyEPY0Q1Udo57 (refresh the preview window after loading for the first time to see the issue)

```
for (let country of countries) {
  country_layers = L.layerGroup();
  $.getJSON('geojson_files/'+country[2]+'/'+country[0]+'.geojson', function(data) {
    sites = L.geoJson(data, {
      //"onEachFeature": forEachFeature,
      "style": {color: country[1], fillPattern: country[4]},
      "pane": country[3]
    });
    sites.addTo(country_layers);
    mymap.addLayer(country_layers);
  });
}
```

This is a part of the array countries:

```
countries = [
  ["neutral_zone_iraq", neutral_zone, "1935_10_03", "neutral_zone", null],
  
  ["afghanistan", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["albania", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["andorra", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["argentina", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["austria", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["belgian_congo", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["belgium", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["bhutan", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["bolivia", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["brazil", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["bulgaria", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["chile", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["colombia", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["costarica", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["cuba", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["czechoslovakia", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["danzig", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["denmark", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["dominican_republic", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["dutch_east_indies", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["finland", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["ecuador", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["el_salvador", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["estonia", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["greece", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["guatemala", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["haiti", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["honduras", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["hungary", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["iceland", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["iran", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["iraq", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["ireland", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["latvia", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["liberia", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["lichtenstein", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["lithuania", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["luxembourg", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["macau", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["mexico", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["monaco", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["nepal", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["netherlands", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["nicaragua", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["norway", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["panama", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["paraguay", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["peru", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["philippines", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["poland", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["portugal", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["portuguese_cape_verde", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["portuguese_east_africa", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["portuguese_guinea", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["portuguese_india", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["portuguese_timor", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["portuguese_west_africa", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["romania", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["san_marino", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["sao_tome_and_principe", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["saudi_arabia", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["siam", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["sweden", neutral, "1936_09_28", "neutral", null],
  ["switzerland", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["tibet", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["turkey", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["uruguay", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["usa", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["vatican", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["venezuela", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["yemen", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["yugoslavia", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  
  ["australia", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["bahamas", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["bahrain", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["barbados", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["basutoland", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["bechuanaland", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["bermuda", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["british_burma", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["british_guiana", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["british_honduras", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["british_hong_kong", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["british_leeward_islands", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["british_malaya", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["british_somaliland", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["british_western_pacific_territories", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["british_windward_islands", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["brunei", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["canada", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["ceylon", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["cyprus", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["egypt", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["falklands", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["gambia", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["gibraltar", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["gold_coast", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["india", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["jamaica", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["kenya", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["kingdom_of_sikkim", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["kuwait", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["maldives", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["malta", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["mauritius", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["new_zealand", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["nigeria", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["north_borneo", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["northern_rhodesia", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["nyasaland", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["oman", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["palestine", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", stripes_neutral],
  ["qatar", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["saint_helena", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["sarawak", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["seychelles", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["sierra_leone", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["south_africa", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["southern_rhodesia", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["swaziland", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["transjordania", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["trinidad_and_tobago", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["tristan_de_cunha", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["trucial_states", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["uganda", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["uk", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["zanzibar", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  
  ["france", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["french_cameroon", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["french_equatorial_africa", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["french_guiana", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["french_india", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["french_indochina", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["french_madagascar", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["french_oceania", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["french_somaliland", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["french_syria", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["french_togoland", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["french_west_africa", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["guadelupe", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["inini", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["martinique", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["morocco", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["tangiers", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["tunis", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  
  ["mongolia", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["tannu_tuva", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  ["ussr", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  
  ["germany", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  
  ["xinjiang", neutral, "1935_10_03", "neutral", null],
  
  ["chengdu_clique", uf_puppet, "1935_10_03", "uf_puppet", null],
  ["chongqing_clique", uf_puppet, "1935_10_03", "uf_puppet", null],
  ["guangdong_clique", uf_puppet, "1935_10_03", "uf_puppet", null],
  ["hebei_chahar_council", uf_puppet, "1935_12_18", "uf_puppet", null],
  ["hunan_clique", uf_puppet, "1935_10_03", "uf_puppet", null],
  ["mianyang_clique", uf_puppet, "1935_10_03", "uf_puppet", null],
  ["nanchong_clique", uf_puppet, "1935_10_03", "uf_puppet", null],
  ["new_guanxi_clique", uf_puppet, "1935_10_03", "uf_puppet", null],
  ["ningxia_ma_clique", uf_puppet, "1935_10_22", "uf_puppet", null],
  ["northeastern_army", uf_puppet, "1935_10_23", "uf_puppet", null],
  ["ningxia_ma_clique", uf_puppet, "1935_10_04", "uf_puppet", null],
  ["pailingmiao_council", uf_puppet, "1935_10_03", "uf_puppet", null],
  ["qinghai_ma_clique", uf_puppet, "1935_10_03", "uf_puppet", null],
  ["shandong_clique", uf_puppet, "1935_10_03", "uf_puppet", null],
  ["shanxi_clique", uf_puppet, "1935_10_23", "uf_puppet", null],
  ["tunganistan", uf_puppet, "1935_10_03", "uf_puppet", null],
  ["xikang_clique", uf_puppet, "1935_10_03", "uf_puppet", null],
  ["yunnan_clique", uf_puppet, "1935_10_03", "uf_puppet", null],
  ["china", uf, "1935_10_03", "uf", null],

  ["chinese_soviet_republic", comintern, "1935_10_22", "comintern", null],

  ["east_chahar", axis_puppet, "1935_10_03", "axis_puppet", null],
  ["east_hebei", axis_puppet, "1935_11_15", "axis_puppet", null],
  ["manchukuo", axis_puppet, "1935_10_03", "axis_puppet", null],
  ["japan", axis, "1935_10_03", "axis", null],
  ["japanese_korea", axis_puppet, "1935_10_03", "axis_puppet", null],
  ["japanese_taiwan", axis_puppet, "1935_10_03", "axis_puppet", null],
  ["kwantung_leased_territory", axis_puppet, "1935_10_03", "axis_puppet", null],
  ["south_seas_mandate", axis_puppet, "1935_10_03", "axis_puppet", null],
  
  ["ethiopia", finland, "1936_07_14", "finland", stripes_finland],
  
  ["italy", italy, "1935_10_03", "italy", null],
  ["italian_east_africa", italy_puppet, "1936_07_14", "italy_puppet", null],
  ["italian_libya", italy_puppet, "1935_10_03", "italy_puppet", null],

  ["republican_africa", comintern_puppet, "1936_10_14", "comintern_puppet", null],
  ["republican_spain", comintern, "1937_01_15", "comintern", null],

  ["ifni", axis_puppet, "1935_10_03", "axis_puppet", null],
  ["nationalist_spain", axis, "1937_01_15", "axis", null],
  ["nationalist_africa", axis_puppet, "1936_10_14", "axis_puppet", null],
  ["spanish_morocco", axis_puppet, "1936_07_18", "axis_puppet", null],
  ["spanish_sahara", axis_puppet, "1935_10_03", "axis_puppet", null]
]
```

and this is an example from the .geojson file:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"Name":"Spanish State","Status":"Nationalist faction in the Spanish civil war","Government":"Unitary personalist dictatorship","Party":"National Movement (Movimiento Nacional)","HoG":"Francisco Franco"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-14.49955,28.101209],[-14.493713,28.083188],[-14.501953,28.080462],[-14.510193,28.067588],[-14.507961,28.064861],[-14.480152,28.076827],[-14.408226,28.057893],[-14.361019,28.046985],[-14.334068,28.042895],[-14.322052,28.048955],[-14.28566,28.083491],[-14.251671,28.11408],[-14.234848,28.142541],[-14.222145,28.162216],[-14.208412,28.164335],[-14.198799,28.173415],[-14.188156,28.171296],[-14.067307,28.198834],[-14.011002,28.207609],[-13.985252,28.22697],[-13.944397,28.22939],[-13.899937,28.275509],[-13.895645,28.288208],[-13.901653,28.303625],[-13.89925,28.303927],[-13.897705,28.31224],[-14.49955,28.101209]]]}}]}
```

handling of panes:

````
mymap.createPane('neutral');
mymap.createPane('uf_occupied');
mymap.createPane('uf_puppet');
mymap.createPane('uf');
mymap.createPane('allies_occupied');
mymap.createPane('allies_puppet');
mymap.createPane('allies');
mymap.createPane('comintern_occupied');
mymap.createPane('comintern_puppet');
mymap.createPane('comintern');
mymap.createPane('finland_occupied');
mymap.createPane('finland');
mymap.createPane('italy_occupied');
mymap.createPane('italy_puppet');
mymap.createPane('italy');
mymap.createPane('axis_occupied');
mymap.createPane('axis_puppet');
mymap.createPane('axis');

mymap.getPane('neutral_zone').style.zIndex = 252;
mymap.getPane('neutral').style.zIndex = 253;
mymap.getPane('uf_occupied').style.zIndex = 254;
mymap.getPane('uf_puppet').style.zIndex = 255;
mymap.getPane('uf').style.zIndex = 256;
mymap.getPane('allies_occupied').style.zIndex = 257;
mymap.getPane('allies_puppet').style.zIndex = 258;
mymap.getPane('allies').style.zIndex = 259;
mymap.getPane('comintern_occupied').style.zIndex = 260;
mymap.getPane('comintern_puppet').style.zIndex = 261;
mymap.getPane('comintern').style.zIndex = 262;
mymap.getPane('finland_occupied').style.zIndex = 263;
mymap.getPane('finland').style.zIndex = 264;
mymap.getPane('italy_occupied').style.zIndex = 265;
mymap.getPane('italy_puppet').style.zIndex = 266;
mymap.getPane('italy').style.zIndex = 267;
mymap.getPane('axis_occupied').style.zIndex = 268;
mymap.getPane('axis_puppet').style.zIndex = 269;
mymap.getPane('axis').style.zIndex = 270;```
````

Comment: Do post the minimal code needed to reproduce the bug. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @IvanSanchez, there, edited

Comment: [Works for me](https://plnkr.co/edit/rfbBWh1d6WduyAf6). Make sure your code reproduces the problem in full. The way you're creating/handling the map panes might be relevant.

Comment: @IvanSanchez Ok, I added the pane handling too. After experimenting more on my website, I found out that Spain is the only region where this happens - I've set the starting location to be somewhere in Africa and this didn't happen, only in Spain. I assume that it has to do something with the geojson shapes. Could it be the size of the files?

Comment: [Still works for me](https://plnkr.co/edit/RXAC4p4w9uJBu9YA). Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example again , then divide-and-conquer your code until you come up with the minimum needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @IvanSanchez Okay, I managed to recreate it finally. [https://plnkr.co/edit/RD9yyEPY0Q1Udo57 if the issue doesn't show up at first, try reloading the preview